# Table storage - Is there a cost/performance differential between reading from Azure Website vs Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles, azure-table-storage

I already have a cloud storage account. I am looking at hosting either an Azure Website or a cloud service, in node.js, but I am confused on a number of points listed below:

If my storage account is in 'Europe North' and if I host a new Node azure website/cloud service also in 'Europe North' then I'm wondering firstly if there's a cost differential between the two possible configurations listed?

*Azure Website (Node.js)  <---> Table Storage.

*Azure Cloud Service (Web/Worker role) <-----> Table Storage.

Also is there any performance gain going with a Cloud Service over the Azure Website?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have a web site or cloud service: when locating storage are in the same data center, you won't incur bandwidth costs. You'll still pay for egress (free tier gives you 165MB free egress daily; shared tier gives you 5GB free egress monthly, and you pay standard rates after that).

Performance: You have different bandwidth availability on the NIC. With a cloud service, you have 100Mbps per core (or 5Mbps with XS). With web sites in free or shared tier, you're sharing the NIC. With reserved tier, you should have the same bandwidth as cloud service, since you have reserved instances.